# MySQL: Flush Privileges Not Effective For Existing Connection

Tags: mysql

So on my database granting/revoking privileges kind of only takes effect after establishing a new connection. I need it effective instantly though, and as I understand this is what `flush privileges` should be for, but for some reason it doesn't work.

My setup:

(there is an established database connection from server1 to database server)

Database server:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SHOW GRANTS FOR user@1.2.3.4;
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>
```

Server1 (IP 1.2.3.4):

```
SHOW GRANTS;
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>

SHOW DATABASES;
> only information_schema, doesn't show any other databases
```

And only after re-establishing the database connection does `SHOW DATABASES` update to show all databases. Same behaviour for when I query `information_schema.tables` to gather available databases.

The `SHOW GRANTS` on the server1 always shows the correct info immediately.

This is reproducible and is the same for revoke commands. MySQL server version is 5.6 if that's important.

Comment: Simple. [flush privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-privileges) doesn't do what you think it does. Its not needed for `GRANT`, `DROP USER`, `CREATE USER` or indeed any SQL manipulation of users. Its only partial purpose is after directly manipulating user tables which aren't needed any more. Your option is to kill of all connections after doing the grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So on my database granting/revoking privileges kind of only takes effect after establishing a new connection.

That is true.

> I need it effective instantly though.

You Can't Do That™.  Changed privileges take effect with new connections.

Comment: okay thank you! couldn't find any documentation about this so I didn't think it just wouldn't work